# Reading and querying large log files using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, parsing, crud

I have a requirement for reading and parsing very large log files (that can be in gigabytes) and sending the paginated result to a JavaScript frontend.

The thing is that the frontend can then apply filters and we cant exactly store the parsed results in memory considering the file size.

So I am looking for suggestions for possible approaches. Some more details regarding my application:

- It is a Hybrid app meaning that it can be deployed on the web and can also be bundled as an electron app in which case the backend is bundled with the UI

Comment: The setup available is not fully clear, but Node streams are built for this https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: @OFRBG you have a point, and as for filters OP can optimise the operation by either sorting the data in certain way that filters can benefit from. Or store the parsed data if it is structured (maybe be even loosely) in a database for future use.

Comment: @OFRBG It's a log reader application that can run on the web as a normal website or it can bundled as an electron app so that the user can download it and run it locally on his system

Comment: @TheWhiteFang Since the application can be bundled as an electron app I don't want the user to have a database as a prerequisite for our application to work. Any idea for how the sorting would work though? If we're reading and parsing data as a stream we'll probably get one line at a time and we can't store much in memory because eventually that would crash the application

Comment: @SGoodman well there's no rule that says you can't use DBs on client app. There are solutions like SQLite and pouchDB which are built to be used for that specific purpose.